# Passing current combobox item to Converter using converterparamter

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, ivalueconverter

I have one Enum Description Converter

```
public class EnumDescriptionConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        //// parameter need current item, but null or "Value"
        if (Enum.IsDefined(value.GetType(), value) == false)
            return System.Windows.DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        string parameterString = Enum.GetName(value.GetType(), value);  
        if (parameterString == null)
            return System.Windows.DependencyProperty.UnsetValue;

        var desc = (value.GetType().GetField(parameterString).GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false).FirstOrDefault() as DescriptionAttribute);
        if (desc != null)
            return desc.Description;
        else
            return parameter.ToString();
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

i like to Pass current combobox item to converter as ConverterParameter

```
<ComboBox Name="test" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2" VerticalAlignment="Center" IsReadOnly="True" >
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource enumDescriptionConverter},ConverterParameter=Value}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
```

but Value is coming as string "Value", when i try binding getting error. Is any way to pass current item ?

Comment: It's not clear to my why you would need a converter parameter at all.  It looks like you're trying to produce the `[Description]` text when present, and the enum name otherwise.  The enum value should come into `Convert()` as the `value` parameter.  Why do you need the additional `parameter` in this case?

Comment: previously i was using string parameterString = parameter as string; var desc = (value.GetType().GetField(parameterString) ; when i get parameter  value, i can avoid calling Enum.GetName(value.GetType(), value);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a converter parameter for this.  Simply replace:

```
value.GetType().GetField(parameterString)
```

with

```
value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString())
```

You can get rid of `parameterString` entirely.  The string representation of a singular enum value always matches the field name for that value (or, in cases where multiple enum elements have the same value, it will match the field name for an *equivalent* value).

Comment: "The string representation of a singular enum value always matches the field name" - not always. try to get string representation of each enumvalue of System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon for example (the same value has different names)

Comment: @ASh Good point.  I should have said it matches the field name of an _equivalent_ or _equal_ value.  Edited.